# How to let long code appear in text width?

Tags: listings, line-breaking

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=R,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\chapter{r code}

\begin{lstlisting}
x <- list(label=c("beta0","beta1","gamma"),est=c(mle$estimate[1],mle$estimate[2],mle$estimate[3]),low=c(-7.7,-0.92,-1),upp=c(-5.6,1.09,1))
pi<-rep(1,n)
library(Bhat)
plkhci(x,nlogf,"beta1",prob=0.9)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I want to insert my code in appendix but some of my code is very long and will out of margin. Is there anyway for the code to appear in text width?

[image: part of the long code disappeared]

Comment: `\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Page 35 of the `listings` [documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) describes line breaking.

In your case, add `breaklines=true` as an option to get the output you want, since the default is no linebreaking.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=R,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\chapter{r code}

\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]
x <- list(label=c("beta0","beta1","gamma"),est=c(mle$estimate[1],mle$estimate[2],mle$estimate[3]),low=c(-7.7,-0.92,-1),upp=c(-5.6,1.09,1))
pi<-rep(1,n)
library(Bhat)
plkhci(x,nlogf,"beta1",prob=0.9)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]